# Object's Deep Compare

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I wrote this function to deeply compare two objects  in JavaScript

```
Equal: function(obj1, obj2) {
  var keys1 = Object.keys(obj1).sort();
  var keys2 = Object.keys(obj2).sort();
  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  // first make sure have same keys.
  if (!keys1.every(function(k, i) {
    return (k === keys2[i]);
  })) {
    return false;
  }
  return keys1.every(function(kk) {
    var v1 = obj1[kk];
    var v2 = obj2[kk];
    if (Array.isArray(v1)) {
      return this.EqualArr(v1, v2);
    } else if (typeof v1 === "object" && v1 !== null) {
      return this.Equal(v1, v2);
    } else {
      return v1 === v2;
    }
  });
},
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

The problem happens at this line:

```
var keys2 = Object.keys(obj2).sort();
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Well, first and foremost, did you check what are you sending to `Equals(obj1, obj2)` method ? Your error means either that `obj2` is undefined, null, or that it contains a key that is undefined or null.

Comment: yes  i'm comparing results from odata and normalement they are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using the UI5 framework, you can make use of the [built-in comparator `jQuery.sap.equal`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.equal).

> *jQuery.sap.equal(a, b, maxDepth?, contains?)*
>   Compares the two given values for equality, especially takes care not to compare arrays and objects by reference, but compares their content.

Here is an example:

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "jquery.sap.global"
], jQuery => console.log(jQuery.sap.equal({
  a: "I'm A",
  b: {
    property: "I'm B",
    c: {
      property: "I'm C",
      array: [1, 2, 3],
      date: new Date("2018-02-28"),
    },
  },
}, {
  a: "I'm A",
  b: {
    property: "I'm B",
    c: {
      property: "I'm C",
      array: [1, 2, 3],
      date: new Date("2018-02-28"),
    },
  },
})));
console.clear();
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

- [How UI5 actually compares the two given objects](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/base/util/equal.js)
- [Other test cases](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/test/sap/ui/core/qunit/base/util/equal.qunit.js)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the invocation to `Object.keys`

This method does not accept `null` or `undefined` as argument. To avoid that you can check objects passed are not falsy.

```
if (!obj1 && !obj2) {
  return false
}
```